# Find a string on one line and return the string directly below the found string - Python or UNIX

Tags: python, find, position

I am having trouble coming up with a way to parse a file in python.
The file has rows with random letters and characters (see below).

```
ABCDBCADBADCBABDDACAABCDB 
1#JHHHF##@@GGIHHHIII==DDS
ACBDAACBABDCCBBDCDBBADADA
ISHFIDH#H@1JD=@HHII##GG=H
CCCDDAABCCBABBADBADBAAABA
%%$$#@GGTTT&%MHTHWAIIHJWI
```

Given a string, e.g. 'BAD' return or print the characters immediately below it.
For this file, the code should return:

```
#@@
##G
MHT
HWA
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Here's what I've started with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
f=open('file.txt')
lines=f.readlines()
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('file.txt'))
x = 0
while x <= num_lines:
    _str = lines[x]
    loc = _str.find('BAD')
    x = x+1
    _str = lines[x]
    print (_str[loc:loc+2]
    x=x+1
```

Comment: `str` is a built-in datatype. Do not overwrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close to the solution. Step through the pairs of lines, find the marker ("BAD") in the first and the word with the same index in the second:

```
marker = 'BAD'
marker_len = len(marker)

for l1, l2 in zip(lines, lines[1:]):
   i = l1.find(marker) # Find the first marker
   while i != -1: # Are there any more markers?
     print(l2[i:i + marker_len])
     i = l1.find(marker, i + marker_len) # Search the rest of l1
# #@@
# ##G
# MHT
# HWA
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great! The l1, l2, and zip are completely new to me!

Comment: l1 and l2 are just variable names.

Comment: FWIW, You don't need to read all the lines. In fact, unless you can guarantee the input is small you shouldn't read all the lines up front. It is sufficient, and far more efficient, to do `for l1, l2 in zip(f, f):`.

Comment: Good to know. I'll adjust the script. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `re` module:

```
import re
str = """ABCDBCADBADCBABDDACAABCDB 
1#JHHHF##@@GGIHHHIII==DDS
ACBDAACBABDCCBBDCDBBADADA
ISHFIDH#H@1JD=@HHII##GG=H
CCCDDAABCCBABBADBADBAAABA
%%$$#@GGTTT&%MHTHWAIIHJWI"""

length = int(len(str)/len(str.split('\n')))
p = re.compile("BAD")
for m in p.finditer(str):
    i = m.start()+length
    j = m.end()+length
    print (str[i:j])
```

Prints:

```
##@
##G
MHT
HWA
```

Comment: What is the meaning of 26?

Comment: Yeah cheers, calculated the offset in the terminal but forgot to include it in the snippet. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Singleline using `re`:

```
import re

data = '''
ABCDBCADBADCBABDDACAABCDB
1#JHHHF##@@GGIHHHIII==DDS
ACBDAACBABDCCBBDCDBBADADA
ISHFIDH#H@1JD=@HHII##GG=H
CCCDDAABCCBABBADBADBAAABA
%%$$#@GGTTT&%MHTHWAIIHJWI
'''

print(re.findall(r'(?=(?:BAD))(?=(?:.{%s}(...)))' % (len(max(data.splitlines())) + 1), data, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

Prints:

```
['#@@', '##G', 'MHT', 'HWA']
```

Explanation of this regexp [here](https://regex101.com/r/CPGKN5/1).